# how to rewrite example.com/abc.html to example.com/abc

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying the below code but not working for me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: Seems to work for me..

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working". This code does the opposite of what you state in the title. However, you shouldn't be "rewriting" from `/abc.html` to `/abc`.

Comment: I mean I need to open mdaziz.co.in/abc.html but I want the URL should be mdaziz.co.in/abc this. I used the above code to fix but don't get solution so can you help?

Comment: Yes, the above code already does that. When you request the URL `/abc` the above rule internally rewrites the request to `/abc.html` which is then served. Are you suggesting that is not happening? Or are you expecting your URLs to be _magically_ changed from `/abc.html` to `/abc` in your HTML source? Because it doesn't do that, if that is what you are expecting?

Comment: yes it's not happening that's the problem. URL are not rewriting

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, enable MultiViews in Apache.

MultiViews hides the file extension in the URL.

```
<Directory "/folder/subfolder/subfolder">

    Options +MultiViews 

</Directory>
```